# Visual Basic - how to prevent keyboard keys in textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a program like this site http://www.lexilogos.com/clavier/araby.htm. When I click on a key like for example "m" it writes "م", so i programmed the buttons in the Visual Basic program to send keystrokes to a textbox. When I tried the code below, when I hit a keyboard key it clicked on the button in Visual Basic that sends the keystroke

```
If (GetAsyncKeyState(65)) Then
    Button19.PerformClick()
End If
```

and it works but it also write the normal keyword that I hit, so it writes two keywords, for example the "m" and "م".

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = "a" Then
            e.KeyChar = "1"
        End If
    End Sub
```

.

Comment: sorry didn't work [photo included](http://www2.0zz0.com/2014/06/27/12/233541938.png)

Comment: it would help if you provide more code, for example the code under Button19?

Comment: ech button have this code
>RichTextBox1.Focus()
>SendKeys.Send("م")
and there is a timer have a lot of this code
>If (GetAsyncKeyState(65)) Then
>Button19.PerformClick()
>End If

Comment: ah! you use  RichTextBox1, to test the code above ,  insert a textbox1,  click with mouse inside (focus)  textbox1  and press on the keyboard the letter "a" OR place the code under `RichTextBox1_KeyPress`

Answer (score 3):

In the event for the Key pressed (`KeyPressed` or `KeyDown`), just assign:

```
e.Handled = true
```

This will prevent the letter to appear on the TextBox. Check is [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about it.

---

You can do a workaround too, but I don't recommend it. Simply handle the `TextChanged` event of the TextBox and delete the text:

```
Sub TB_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry didn't work [photo included](http://www10.0zz0.com/2014/06/27/12/170756246.png)

Comment: did you tried my solution? As @ooopsoft said, you have to use your control name (`RichTextBox1`) instead of `TextBox1` (as my example)

Comment: i tried richTextBox1_KeyPress but it also disabled my code > If (GetAsyncKeyState(65)) Then> Button20.PerformClick()> End If